# Beginning Java Programming

Tags: java

Ok, so I am working on an assignment for my Java Programming Class.  The assignment is as follows (and code will be at the end):
Suppose that the tuition for a university is $10,000 this year and increases 5% each year.  Write a program that computes the tuition in ten years and the total cost of four years' worth of tuition in ten years. Amounts should be to two decimal places.  I can't figure out where I went wrong and how to fix it.  When I try to run it, nothing happens, nothing displays AT ALL! :( Here is my code:

```
public class FutureTuitionPrice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double tuition = 10000;
        double count = 0;
        double increase = 1.05;
        double increasedTuition = 0;

        do {
            increasedTuition = tuition * increase;

        } while(count <=10);
        count++;

        if (count ==10);
        System.out.print("Tuition in ten years is $ \n" + increasedTuition);        
        do {
            increasedTuition = tuition * increase;
        }while (count==10 && count < 14);
        count ++;
         if (count ==14);
         System.out.print("The four-year tuitiuon in ten years is $ " + increasedTuition);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Execute your do/while loop on paper, and note the value of the count variable at each iteration.

Comment: Your in a never ending loop.

Comment: Debug the code. Should help in the future as well.

Comment: The most important skill for a programmer is [learning how to debug](http://samizdat.mines.edu/howto/HowToBeAProgrammer.html#id2790282).  If you sit down with the eclipse debugger and learn how to use it, you will find yourself a much better programmer now and many things will be easier in the future.

Comment: Where is the debugger? It will catch issues that aren't showing immediately in my code?

Comment: @Tammy A tutorial on the Eclipse debugger: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html - you will be able to stop the code at any point (breakpoint) and look at the state of every thing.  Or step through it line by line and see how things change.

Answer (score 5):

```
double count = 0;
do {
    increasedTuition = tuition * increase;
} while(count <=10);
```

There is nothing in this segment of code that will increment count.  It will continue to loop eternally.

Move your count++ inside the brace brackets to make count eventually reach 10.

Comment: Thank you! I will go try that now! So, did I do right as far as the next loop (getting from count 10 to 14 to figure out the cost of 4 years of tuition?)

Comment: So why don't you write it correctly instead of suggesting?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Ok, boss :)

Comment: Ok, I did change that and the program now runs BUT it is only doing one iteration so it is giving me the same result for both numbers displayed.

Comment: @Tammy You should try to respond to the comments on the question rather than asking people to fix the code for you and point out every little mistake. Otherwise, you will find yourself in the same situation with every upcoming homework assignment.

Comment: @ Ingo Burk: I am not trying to get anyone to fix every little mistake.  I did comment on here to people. I am new to Java and just looking for a little guidance. I kinda thought that is what this was for.

Comment: @Tammy You need to think very carefully about what you are trying to do.  Think about the conditions you have chosen for the second while loop.  Also examine your variable selection within the second loop.  Lastly, if(count==10); simply checks if count is equal to ten.  If you leave the ; off then it will conditionally perform the statement on the next line.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out...

```
    double tuition = 10000;
    double count = 1;
    double percentageIncrease = 1.05;
    double increasedTuition;
    double sumOfTuitionAfterFourYears = 0;
    double increasedTuitionTwo;

    do {
        //This is the correct incremental formular
        tuition = tuition * percentageIncrease;
        //increasedTuition = increasedTuition * percentageIncrease;
        count++;

        //Formatting the number of digits after the decimal point
        increasedTuition = (int)(tuition * 100) / 100.0;

        //This if statement must be inside the loop body
        if (count > 10) //Note, do not put a semi-colon here
        System.out.println("Tuition in ten years is " + increasedTuition);

    } while (count <= 10); //End of first loop

    do {
        increasedTuition = increasedTuition * percentageIncrease;

            //Formatting the number of digits after the decimal point
            increasedTuitionTwo = (int)(increasedTuition * 100) / 100.0;

            //Adding the result above on each iteration pass
            sumOfTuitionAfterFourYears += increasedTuitionTwo;

            if (count == 14) 
            System.out.println("The sum of four years tuition starting from 10 years is " + sumOfTuitionAfterFourYears);

        //Increments the count from 10 since our base tuition is the last tuition in the last loop
        //You can also write your continuation-condition like this: (count >= 10 && count <= 14). 
        //You will get the same result without changing the base tuition
        count++; 

    } while (count <= 14); //End of second loop
```

Answer (score -2):

Your program is in an endless loop

```
     do {

          increasedTuition = tuition * increase;
          ++count;//incrementing count each cycle

     } while(count <=10);
```

Comment: You should check the syntax. Don't mix `do while` loops with `while` ones.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I don't know where my mind was,  fixed the code snippet, the issue is still that he never was incrementing his count.